# May I know why there is a python executing error , saying full_dict with issue , I am a newb with python

Tags: python, github

I am a newb of python.

I would like to use this script in GitHub
https://github.com/marcoymh/CCASS_shareholdings
But when I run , it said the `"AttributeError: 'Shareholdings' object has no attribute 'full_dict'`
"
What wrong I have done ?
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IFfD.jpg)

From the readme document : the author said the following ,  I try to run the program with

***the code I run in pycharm***

```
import datetime
from shareholdings import *

start_date = datetime.date(2021, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2021, 3, 2)
print(start_date)
stock = '00708'
Shareholdings(stock,start_date,end_date).scrap_all()
Shareholdings(stock,start_date,end_date).trend_plot()
```

#### readme

**Step 1**
import shareholdings.py
Create Shareholdings object with below parameters
  :param stock_code: int
  :param start_date: datetime.date
  :param end_date: datetime.date

**Step 2**
run the function trend_plot

1. to generate top 10 shareholdings time series plot 'top_10_plot.png'
2. to generate csv file 'tabular_data.csv' as table with filter in excel

**Step 3**
run the function transaction_finder with below parameter
  :param threshold: float > 0 e.g. threshold = 0.01 => 1.0%
  to generate csv file 'transaction_report.csv' which lists out all potential transaction participants for
  corresponding threshold

Many thanks for you help.

Comment: Another image is here .

Comment: https://ibb.co/JKMNTj2

Answer (score 0):

The code in github seems to be badly written. It should have initialised `full_dict` itself.

Eitherway, you should be writing your code like this:

```py
shareholdings = Shareholdings(stock,start_date,end_date)
shareholdings.scrap_all()
shareholdings.trend_plot()
```

Comment: thanks  , I run but unluckily it shows another error message .https://ibb.co/Y0xMns5

Comment: Instead of `ls.sort(key=..., reverse=...)` try using `ls = sorted(ls, key=..., reverse=...)`